# How do I access an object's keys' values? Looking to populate a table from object data

Tags: javascript, arrays

Context: new to javascript, and trying to create a student loan calculator webapp for practice. Currently working on "part 1" where you can submit a loan, it's balance, and interest rate; and a table with your submitted loans will populate as you add them.

1. On form submit, input data is used to make a new object (loanObj) using an object constructor. That new object is pushed into an array (loanArray) for storage.
2. On form submit, I'd like a table to automatically populate with loanObj's data. I attempt that by iterating through the loanArray to count each object, and then iterating through each object's keys, creating the table rows and cells along the way.

So far, I am able to do all those things except access the key's value. I.e. it outputs 'undefined' instead of 5000 and 5%, etc.

Here is a snippet of the code relevant to my problem:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < loanArray.length; i++) {
          //create table row for each loan object in array
          var tr = document.createElement('tr');

          //create table cell for each loan property (keys)
          var loanKeys = Object.keys(loanArray[i]);
          for (var j = 0; j < loanKeys.length; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            //create text node for key data
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(loanKeys[j].value));
            tr.appendChild(td); 
          }
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        }
```

The full fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/v5goLto9/1/

Please help a noob out! And feel free to give me feedback on my code structure/logic/overall!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate on the object values directly, without the keys, as in the following code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < loanArray.length; i++) {
          //create table row for each loan object in array
          var tr = document.createElement('tr');

          //create table cell for each loan property (keys)
         
          for (var j in loanArray[i]) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            //create text node for key data
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(loanArray[i][j]));
            tr.appendChild(td); 
          }
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        }
```

Comment: Sweet, it worked! I had not known about that approach, thanks for introducing it to me. I've only been playing around with javascript for a few weeks.

Comment: Now, the issue is that it iterates over all the objects properties, including object methods that are defined within the object constructor. Is there a way to iterate through the object while skipping/ignoring the methods?

Comment: to exclude inherited properties, check hasOwnProperty https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty to exclude functions you can use the typeof to exclude them https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Perfect, yes I scoured stackoverflow for the typeof solution as well, thanks for the tips, it's working out well